# how to reslve the c2660 compiler error for On_WM_MENUSELECT message?

Tags: mfc

I am using the On_WM_MENUSELECT message for the menu item click event.
but at the compiler throws following error.
error C2660: 'CSplashToolBarWnd::OnMenuSelect' : function does not take 4 arguments e:\splashid\splashidtoolbar\splashidtoolbar\splasheditwnd.h 69 SplashIDToolBar

Answer (score 0):

Well, [it really does not take 4 arguments](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hd5h5a75%28VS.80%29.aspx):

```
afx_msg void OnMenuSelect( 
   UINT nItemID, 
   UINT nFlags, 
   HMENU hSysMenu  
);                       // only 3 arguments
```

Comment: In WTL it takes four arguemets: LRESULT OnMenuSelect(UINT uMsg, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam, BOOL& bHandled)  refer http://www.ecs.syr.edu/faculty/fawcett/handouts/cse778/WTL/Include/AtlCtrlw.h adding four arguements that problem has been solved